# Issue with Azure Log Analytics Workbook access for external user

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am struggling to share a workbook in a Log Analytics workspace with an external user.

I have applied roles up to 'Owner' to see if we could get it working and then back off with the rights until we find the correct ones.

Share the workbook using the link

[share window in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXjQC.png)

But the user still cannot access it - it is a brand new workbook and others can see it.

[Screen shot of error user is seeing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkrqj.png)

The user has also been added to the Language resource that is generating the report in the Log Analytics Workspace.

The user is already using and has access to the Language resource. Any assistance would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the workbooks view was not able to find that specific resource as that user.

Workbooks doesn't know "why" it wasn't found, only that it wasn't found.  It could be lack of access, it could be RBAC settings, etc.

If you have the user go to the full workbooks browse view (type workbooks into the search bar at the top of the portal), can they find the workbook that way?

The user needs access to the subscription/resource group where the workbook is saved, to read the content of the workbook. They then need standard query/etc access on any resources referenced *inside* the workbook (usually from `monitoring reader` role)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the answer - the workbook is also a resource, but not quite accessed in the same way as the main resources where it is hosted.

So you need to click on ALL workbooks and you should get a list, in that list there is a small menu against each workbook (the 3 dots) and in there you have the option to view resource - that is where you need to add in Monitoring Reader and Log Reader as roles.

As well as the Log Analysis Workspace resource that @John Gardner also helpfully suggested.

Handy hidden access to the workspace resource (aargh)

Comment: you don't need to go to the context menu.  As said, use the standard resource browse the way every azure resource has, search for the workbook(s) in question, and open them up by clicking the link in the grid.  You'll get a standard azure resource view that has all those options.